# Perl Net::Curl::Multi “failed writing received data to disk/application” error

Tags: perl, curl

I used Perl's `Net::Curl` module to get contents from some URL. But when my code run at line:

```
while (my ($msg, $curl_cur, $result) = $curl_multi->info_read())
```

I found that `$result` is `failed writing received data to disk/application`.

What does "failed writing received data to disk/application" mean?
How can I avoid this error?

Comment: Can you show more code?